# For which values of the parameter, $f(x, y)$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For which values of $\alpha$, the following function is differentiable at the origin?

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2y}{(x^4+y^2)^{\alpha}} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\\\ 0 & (x, y) = (0, 0)\end{cases}$$

*attempts*

I know that continuity is not a sufficient condition for a function to be differentiable at a point, yet it's necessary because if $f$ is not continuous then it's not differentiable (at a point).

Then I at least need the continuity, when restricting to the lines though the origin $y = mx$ I get

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x, mx) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{mx^3}{(x^{2\alpha}(x^2+m^2)} = 0 \quad \iff \alpha < \frac{3}{2}$$

Now, I know that for some $f$, if $\exists$ the partial derivatives at a point of $f$ and they are continuous too, then $f$ is differentiable at that point.

- Is there a rapider way to check for the differentiability when $f$ depends on a parameter, or should I check for existence and continuity of $\partial f$?

Thank you.

Comment: I think $\alpha\leq0$.

Comment: Forget continuity of first partials. Go back to the definition of differentiability at a point.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you so much! I think I got it!!

Comment: @TedShifrin Uhm perhaps I accelerated things too fast... Can you check this? Differentability implies:
$$\lim_{(h, k)\to (0, 0)} \frac{f(h, k) - f(0, 0) - h f_x(h, 0) - k f_y(0, k)}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} \to 0$$

I calculated that both $f_x(h, 0) = f_y(0, k) = 0$ hence it remains the pure limit. 
Yet
$$\lim_{(h, k)\to (0, 0)} \frac{f(h, k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

seems to not give a unique $\alpha$. For example: $h = k$ gives $\alpha < 1$ whereas $h = k^2$ gives $\alpha < 3/4$...

Comment: Checking along lines through the origin is not conclusive

Comment: @FShrike Indeed, I got it. But how then could I get a "final" answer about?

Comment: Your definition is messed up. Those partial derivatives should be evaluated at the origin!! But, yes, you need to know for what values of $\alpha$ you will have $\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{f(h,k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} = 0$!!

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I wrote bad. (Though they are zero anyway)

Comment: Writing a complete and slightly more general answer, request you to wait

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thank you so much, I appreciate that. No rush!

Comment: @Numb3rs I need to tender an apology at this point. While the technique I mentioned for continuity works very nicely, it breaks down horribly for differentiability, to the extent that I have been unable to fix the answer with consistent effort. I would like you to remove the acceptance and upvote so that I can delete the answer, but I promise that I'll be back because this is a question which deserves a very good answer. Once again I'm really sorry about this. Having said that, I still believe that $\alpha < \frac 34$ is the differentiability threshold, although I need to check this.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Oh, don't worry, really. I am not aware about the website policies, in terms of "wrong" or incomplete answers and what to do in case. I'm sorry to hear that I have to unaccept it, but if this makes you more serene about, I will. I will wait (with no rush at all) for another answer. I still thank you about the continuity part which I really get and it was realyl useful. I will try myself abit about differentiability, just because I need to work myself too, not just waiting. Thank you again! P.s. I need you to edit the answer in order to unaccept it. Even a slight edit

Comment: +1 for this nice question

Comment: This question is very good and clearly is beyond my best efforts. I have offered a bounty of +100 to anyone who solves this question, but am willing to converse with anyone who asks me how I got the estimates shown in the bounty message.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I have to thank you again for this! By the way, I got an idea which I believe to actually be wrong, or incomplete. But I don't know if I will be able to develop here completely, in a comment. I could try to shrink it, because it's actually not a big deal in the end. Would you take a look at it and straightly tell me how wrong is it? :D

Comment: @Numb3rs Sure, try and fit the idea in one or two comments and I will look at it and let you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
f(x,y)=\frac{x^{2}y}{(x^{4}+y^{2})^{a}}.
$$
Since $\partial_{x}f(0,0)=\partial_{y}f(0,0)=0$, we have
\begin{align*}
& \frac{f(x,y)-\partial_{x}f(0,0)(x-0)-\partial_{y}f(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}
}\\
& =\frac{x^{2}y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{4}+y^{2})^{a}}.
\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{2}|y|}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{4}+y^{2})^{a}}  & =\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}
}(x^{4})^{1/4}(y^{2})^{1/2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{4}+y^{2})^{a}}\leq
\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{4}+y^{2})^{1/4+1/2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}
(x^{4}+y^{2})^{a}}\\
& =\frac{(x^{4}+y^{2})^{1/4+1/2}}{(x^{4}+y^{2})^{a}}=(x^{4}+y^{2}
)^{3/4-a}\rightarrow0
\end{align*}
if $\frac{3}{4}>a$. If $a\ge \frac{3}{4}$, $x^{2}=y$ with $x>0$ gives
$$
\frac{x^{4}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+x^{4}}(x^{4}+x^{4})^{a}}=\frac{x^{4}}{2^{a}
\sqrt{1+x^{2}}x^{1+4a}}=\frac{x^{3-4a}}{2^{a}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}
[c]{cc}
\frac{1}{2^{a}} & \text{if }a=\frac{3}{4}.\\
\infty & \text{if }a>\frac{3}{4}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: the said quantity does not go to infinity when $\alpha=3/4$. the denominator goes to a non zero constant for every positive $a$. i agree with the first part,though.

Comment: thanks. I changed it

Comment: Thank you very much.i would like you to add some details in the inequality you used above for $a<3/4$, it looks like cauchy Schwarz or holder but I am not sure

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I think he just used some majorizations, like when you for example write $x^2 \leq x^2+y^2$ or when you majorize with the $\ell^2$ norm like $|x| + |y| \leq C\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and so on.
In the very first passage he uses a trick though, for $(x^4)^{1/4}(y^2)^{1/2}$ is just $xy$.
Smooth!

Comment: @Numb3rs I see it! Nice point out. Very smooth , superb stuff!